# Empty screen is also saved

Tags: java, android

Paint app where you can delete and save. Basically i don't want to save empty screen. Bitmap is converted to base64. But right now it shows base64 value in logs even when it's empty. How to do it? 
Troubleshooting: i have tired checking if bitmap is empty, also tried if bytearray is empty. Nothing worked. Any guidance??

```
 public class PaintView extends View { 
 Canvas mCanvas;  // 1
Bitmap mBitmap ,emptyBitmap ; //2 , to hold the pixels
Path mPath; // 3, encapsulates outline representing (multiple contuer) straight lines ,curves. can be drawn with canvas.drawpath(path,paint)
Paint mPaint; //4
private float mX, mY;
private static final float TOUCH_TOLERANCE = 5;
Context context;
public PaintView(Context context, @Nullable AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
    this.context = context;
    mPath = new Path();
    mPaint = new Paint();
    mPaint.setAntiAlias(true); //smoothes the edges of what is being drawn
    mPaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE); // style is specifies as stroke. Options: Fill,fill and stroke
    mPaint.setColor(Color.BLACK);
    mPaint.setStrokeJoin(Paint.Join.ROUND); //more options for round
    mPaint.setStrokeWidth(4f);
}


@Override //called when the size of view is changed
protected void onSizeChanged(int w, int h, int oldw, int oldh) {
    super.onSizeChanged(w, h, oldw, oldh);
  mBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(w, h, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
       mCanvas = new Canvas(mBitmap);
}
    public String getEncoded64ImageStringFromBitmap(Bitmap bitmap) {
    ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100 , stream);
    byte[] byteFormat = stream.toByteArray();
    String imgString = Base64.encodeToString(byteFormat, Base64.DEFAULT);
    Log.d("check", "saved successfully");
    return imgString;
}
```

MainActivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
Button button_clear_canvas;
private PaintView canvas;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    canvas = findViewById(R.id.canvasview);
    button_clear_canvas = findViewById(R.id.button_clear_canvas);
    button_clear_canvas.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            SaveDialog();
        }
    });
}
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_erase,menu);
    return true;
}
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()){
        case R.id.erase:
            CreateDialog();
    }
    return true;
}
public void SaveDialog(){
    AlertDialog.Builder mBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    mBuilder.setMessage("Are you sure you want to save?");
    mBuilder.setPositiveButton("YES", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
            try {
                if(canvas.mBitmap != null){
                    canvas.getEncoded64ImageStringFromBitmap(canvas.mBitmap);
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.v("log_tag", e.toString());
            }
        }
    });
    mBuilder.setNegativeButton("NO",null);
    AlertDialog alertDialog = mBuilder.create();
    alertDialog.show();
}
public void CreateDialog(){
                    AlertDialog.Builder mBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
            mBuilder.setMessage("Are you sure ?");
            mBuilder.setPositiveButton("YES", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                 public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                canvas.OnClearCanvas();
            }
            });
            mBuilder.setNegativeButton("NO",null);
            AlertDialog alertDialog = mBuilder.create();
            alertDialog.show();
}
```

Comment: empty screen converted to base64 the result is not certain?

Comment: I just sorted on my own. Thank you :)